# How to send Post request with String params with flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Hi everyone i need to send some string paramaters to the server with flutter, but the http package sends json as paramater to the server not string.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps set the `body` parameter to a `Map` in the `http.post` call?

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var url = 'http://example.com/post';
var response = await http.post(url, body: {'name': 'doodle', 'color': 'blue'});
print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('Response body: ${response.body}');
```

Comment: It's worked, my mistake was using this line json.encode(body).Thanks